# Eclipse not open Run Configuration pop-up that allow to select testng.xml configuration file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng, testng-eclipse

Before I reinstalled my computer and eclipse, when I right click on Java test class `-> Run as -> TestNG Test`, a "Run Configuration" pop-up box is displayed and let me choose what xml configuration file I want to run my test with. But now, instead of letting me choose, Eclipse create a default file named `...testng-customsuite.xml` and run my test by it. Anyone know how to enable this function again? I'm using the latest versions of TestNG, Eclipse and java IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Run->Run Configuration` in eclipse. There you will find the configuration which was used to run your application last time. You can edit the program args/VM argument.

[image]

Comment: I already tried this before. but it's not helped. It only runs all the classes I listed in xml file instead of running my class test that i choose